# Repeat some elements in r

Tags: r, vector, seq, rep

i have a vector that contain :

```
my.var <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
my.var
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f"
```

I wanna use only the `rep` and `seq` functions to get as outout :

```
"a" "b" "c" "b" "c" "d" "c" "d" "e" "d" "e" "f"
```

Comment: for kicks `m <- matrix(0, 4, 3); letters[t(row(m) + col(m) - 1)]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Or

```
x <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
n <- 3
x[seq_len(n)+rep(0:(length(x)-n), each=n)]
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "b" "c" "d" "c" "d" "e" "d" "e" "f"
```

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
c(t(matrix(my.var, nrow=length(my.var)+1, ncol=3)[1:4,]))
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "b" "c" "d" "c" "d" "e" "d" "e" "f"
```

Or

```
c(apply(embed(my.var,3), 1, rev))
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "b" "c" "d" "c" "d" "e" "d" "e" "f"
```

Or

```
library(data.table)
unlist(na.omit(setDT(shift(my.var, 0:3, type='lead'))), use.names=FALSE)
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "b" "c" "d" "c" "d" "e" "d" "e" "f"
```